# valign property of div tag?

Tags: html, css

I have used `<div align="center">` and put the image inside the div tag. Well the image is at the center but not at the middle. The image started from the top of div tag and placing at the center but I want it to be placed at the middle not at the top.

When I googled it I found `<td valign="middle">`. and its working as I intended and below is what I have designed after googling,

```
  <div align="center" style="width:510px;height:510px;margin-left:300px">
  <table style="width:510px;height:510px">
  <tr>
  <td align="center" valign="middle">
  <img id="main" src="dock.jpg" style="max-width:500px;max-height:500px"/> 
  </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  </div>
```

But using a table for these purpose is it harmful ? Because I have tried `<div align="center" style="vertical-align:middle">` but does not seem to work as i expected and please let me know if there is a way to do without table ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `<div align="center">` either really, its been deprecated:

http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/div/align

> This attribute is deprecated. The correct method for aligning a div is
>   to use the CSS text-align attribute.

I'm not certain on the best way of vertically aligning `div`'s (although you may find [this article](http://css-tricks.com/2597-what-is-vertical-align/) worth reading), but I know that you are right, you shouldn't use `table`s as a solution. `Table` should only be used when creating a table of data results for example, never layout purposes.

Comment: Thanks for your information and about valign property of div?

Answer (score 0):

This will help you i think so:
just give #to div. and then style it in CSS as follow:

```
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
right: 50%;
width: _px;
height: _px;
margin: half of the width, half of the height;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. May help you.

```
  <div style="width:510px;height:510px;border:1px solid;margin:auto;">
  <table style="width:100%; height:100%;">
  <tr>
  <td align="center">
  <img id="main" src="wp1.JPG" style="max-width:300px;max-height:300px;"/> 
  </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  </div>
```